# Uncaught SyntaxError: "Unexpected token )" | If else statement in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, syntax

It seems my if else condition has a syntax error, can somebody help? The console spits out this link { /home/ccuser/workspace/javascript_101_Unit_3_v2/rockPaperScissors.js:38
}); } and an error points to the ")"

```
  userInput = userInput.toLowerCase();
  if (userInput !== "rock" && userInput !== "paper" && userInput !== "scissor") {
    console.log("Error");
  } else {
    return userInput;
  }
}

const getComputerChoice = () => {
  const randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
  switch(randomNumber){
    case 0: return "scissor";
    break;
    case 1: return "rock";
    break;
    default: return "paper";
    break;
  }
}

const determinWinner = (userChoice, computerChoice) => {
  if(userChoice === computerChoice){
    return "Its a tie";
  } else if (userChoice === "rock" && computerChoice ==="scissor"){
    return "The user won";
  } else if (userChoice === "paper" && computerChoice ==="rock"){
    return "The user won";
  } else if (userChoice === "scissor" && computerChoice ==="paper"){
    return "The user won";
  } else if (userChoice === "rock" && computerChoice ==="paper"){
    return "The computer won";
  } else if (userChoice === "paper" && computerChoice ==="scissor"){
    return "The computer won";
  } else if (userChoice === "scissor" && computerChoice ==="rock"){
    return "The computer won";
  }
```

Comment: where is the unexpected token? (the error tells you the location)

Comment: Your `if`s and `else if`s are good, but you need to close your function!

Comment: Are you sure the code you pasted here is actually from `rockPaperScissors.js` mentioned in the beginning? Also, which line is line 38?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You defining an enclosure, but you're missing the final `}`

```
  const determinWinner = (userChoice, computerChoice) => {
  if(userChoice === computerChoice){
    return "Its a tie";
  } else if (userChoice === "rock" && computerChoice ==="scissor"){
    return "The user won";
  } else if (userChoice === "paper" && computerChoice ==="rock"){
    return "The user won";
  } else if (userChoice === "scissor" && computerChoice ==="paper"){
    return "The user won";
  } else if (userChoice === "rock" && computerChoice ==="paper"){
    return "The computer won";
  } else if (userChoice === "paper" && computerChoice ==="scissor"){
    return "The computer won";
  } else if (userChoice === "scissor" && computerChoice ==="rock"){
    return "The computer won";
  }
}
```

Comment: What a rookie mistake. Thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 1):

You are just missing the last/closing `}` for your `determinWinner(...)` method.

This is how you code should look like!

```
const determinWinner = (userChoice, computerChoice) => {
  if(userChoice === computerChoice){
    return "Its a tie";
  } else if (userChoice === "rock" && computerChoice ==="scissor"){
    return "The user won";
  } else if (userChoice === "paper" && computerChoice ==="rock"){
    return "The user won";
  } else if (userChoice === "scissor" && computerChoice ==="paper"){
    return "The user won";
  } else if (userChoice === "rock" && computerChoice ==="paper"){
    return "The computer won";
  } else if (userChoice === "paper" && computerChoice ==="scissor"){
    return "The computer won";
  } else if (userChoice === "scissor" && computerChoice ==="rock"){
    return "The computer won";
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:
At the end of `computerChoice){`, add `:` and see if that works!